# Next Line problems with spacing

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

My program below prompts the user for how many children they have in their class. After entering the number they will enter all of the names of their students (first) and (last). Because of this I entered a scan Next Line statement instead of just scan.next. Because of this whatever number you enter the program will prompt you for one less. Please help.

```
 public class studentRoster {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);


     String [] students;
     int size;

     System.out.println("Enter the amount of students in your class: ");
     size = scan.nextInt();

     students = new String[size];

     for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++ ){
            System.out.println("Enter a student name: ");
            students [i] = scan.next();


       }

                 System.out.println("Student Roster");

     for ( int i = 0;  i < students.length; i++ ){
            System.out.println(students[i]);

           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: It's supposed to say scan.next line

Comment: So my question is how do I make it read in the first and last name.

Comment: would this work? `students[i] = scan.next() + " " + scan.next();`

Comment: I'll try, and tell you if it works

Comment: Ian Fell it forces them to enter their last name

Comment: My mistake but I forgot to tell you they can either enter their first name or first and last

Comment: Instead of adding comments telling us what the question _should have_ said, you should just edit the question to say that.

Answer (score 2):

Using scan.next() only captures up to the first space encountered, so you'll want to use .nextLine() if the user is entering both the first and last name at the same time.

To make this code work, add `scan.nextLine();` after you assign `size`to the user input. Then, change `students [i] = scan.next();` to `students [i] = scan.nextLine();`.

The reason you need to do this is because `.nextInt()` doesn't take in the last newline of the user's input, so you need to call `.nextLine()` to account for that.

---

```
public class StudentRoster {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);


     String [] students;
     int size;

     System.out.print("Enter the amount of students in your class: ");
     size = scan.nextInt();
     scan.nextLine();
     students = new String[size];

     for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++ ){
            System.out.print("Enter a student name: ");
            students [i] = scan.nextLine();

       }

                 System.out.println("Student Roster");

     for ( int i = 0;  i < students.length; i++ ){
            System.out.println(students[i]);

           }
        }
     }
```

---

Test output

`Enter the amount of students in your class: 4 
Enter a student name: john Q
Enter a student name: albert E
Enter a student name: tyler D
Enter a student name: mickey M
Student Roster
john Q
albert E
tyler D
mickey M`

Comment: Yeah but then it skips a line

Comment: Charles so if you enter you have 4 children it will only prompt you for 3

Comment: Charles How do i change the last for loop

Comment: I never learned how to do a colon and stuff , is there a different way?

Comment: @calvinjackson Sorry, my IDE automatically switched it.. you don't need to change the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this line

```
size = scan.nextInt();
```

becuase **nextInt()** method doesn't consume all the input buffer, it leaves the last **(\n)** character. When you call nextLine() after that it will not wait for the user to enter any thing but it will consume the **(\n)** character left in the buffer as a residue from the previous **nextInt()** method
so to correct this you have 2 options :

1. put additional scan.nextLine() directly after each scan.nextInt() method to consume the (\n)
   `size = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    students = new String[size];
    //your code`
2. Get the size as a string then convert it to int
   `String temp = scan.nextLine();
    int size = Integer.parseInt(temp);`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use an object better suited for your purpose (I think it's easier to hold data and improves readability):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentRoster {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Student[] students;
        int size;
        String name;
        String lastname;

        System.out.println("Enter the amount of students in your class: ");
        size = scan.nextInt();

        students = new Student[size];
        Student student;
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            student = new Student();
            System.out.println("Enter a student name: ");
            name = scan.next();

            System.out.println("Enter a student lastname: ");
            lastname = scan.next();

            student.setName(name);
            student.setLastname(lastname);
            students[i] = student;
        }

        System.out.println("Student Roster");
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(students[i].getName());
            System.out.println(students[i].getLastname());
        }

    }

    static class Student {
        String name;
        String lastname;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }

        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }
    }
}
```